# get list of loaded classes by Dalvik vm

Tags: android

Is it possible to get list of all loaded classes by the android vm programatically.

If yes, how?

I am able to get all the running processes through code, but i want to list all the classes.

Comment: i tried these classes : ActivityManager to get running processes. and ApplicationInfo. both of no use to me. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add log in the Dalvik ClassLoader.